# How to break html table into two columns with alternating row background color

Tags: html, css

I'm dealing with this problem for quite a while now and it seems there's no real solution on any paltform to find.
Here's what the end result should look like. 
[image]

This is the table structure.

```
   <table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="7px">
        <tr>
            <td><b><?php echo $title_form_database; ?></b></td>
            <td><?php echo $data_from_database; ?></td>
        </tr>
   </table>
```

So each property e.g.(max. Leistung) and the data infront of it is a row. 
What I want is to break the table in two columns as seen in the picture. 
I can't set a specific number of rows because I don't know how many properties each product has and it's loaded dynamically from the DB.
Also what I'm wondering is how to deal with the background colors of the rows.

Comment: _“I can't set a specific number of rows because I don't know how many properties each product has and it's loaded dynamically from the DB.”_ - dynamically is the keyword here - once you got the data, you can count how many properties you have, and then divide that by two. _“Also what I'm wondering is how to deal with the background colors of the rows.”_ - replace “wondering” with doing some actual _research_, please. “table rows alternating colors” or similar should find you results in no time.

Comment: Alternating background colors is easy: `tr:nth-child(odd) {background goes here;}`. The rest, that depends on your setup. Do you want the first six records in the left column and the next six in the right one, or do you want to build the table from top to bottom. Are you sure you always want two columns or does it need to be responsive? What should happen when you have, say, 11 records? Things like that, without knowing what you want make it much harder to answer. Clarify!

Comment: @misorude I already know how to set alternate background colors for table rows. What I din't know was when you place two tables next to eachother, how to have that continues background color in the whole width of the conainer throughout both tables.

Comment: @DevMan You want two tables side by side? Please mention that kind of detail in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that with css selectors. I think this is what you're lokoing for:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #CCC;
  }
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #FFF
  }
```